# How can you convert a string with varying length to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a list that has strings with `Y-M-D` (eg. 2010-01-14) format, but some don't have the month and/or the day. I've tried doing it based on the length but it became long and messy. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do the strings that do not have a month and/or day look like?

Comment: what will be your input and expected output?

Comment: Try to parse as Y-M-D, if that fails, try to parse as Y-M…?

Comment: *"some don't have the month and/or the day"* - to me this sounds kind of desperate, how would you tell if the month or the day is provided then?

Comment: Dates are just the format but with removed months and sometimes days (2010-01-14, 2010-01, 2010)

Comment: Does it even make sense to create a *datetime*, accurate to the microsecond, from "2010"?

Comment: @NikolaStoyanov - how do you wanna tell if "01" in "2010-01" is for month or a day?

Comment: It's in a Y-m-d format, meaning it is a month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this satisfy your needs: [dateutil's parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) with a default date, Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

for s in '2021', '2021-01', '2021-02-03':
    print(parser.parse(s, default=datetime(2021,1,1)))
    
2021-01-01 00:00:00
2021-01-01 00:00:00
2021-02-03 00:00:00
```